# Implications of training a deep network on batches using different sampling methods

Tags: classification, deep-learning, unbalanced-classes, training-error

During training of a deep network on data with high class-imbalance, I notice the network's predictions tend to mimic the class distribution in the training batches.

What is the expected behavior of a network's predictions, when trained on batches that alternate on the sampling method? That is for example over the first half of the training using only batches that have equal ammount of all classes, and the second half use random samples which represent the true distribution. And variations of this, like alternating like this in every subsequental batch during training.

Would the training loss just start oscillating never converging as we are training it on "different" things. Or could it be seen as some kind of hierarchical learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be worrying that the network predictions match the class distributions, since a perfect classifier would do the same. So it's a good thing.

If your goal is to minimize the test error, and you suspect that the test set has a different class distribution, then you can minimize the expected test loss by setting a custom cost matrix for misclassifications.

If you alternate batches, it's possible that the network would have a hard time converging, although if you used any form of SGD with momentum it probably wouldn't be a big deal. I don't see how it would be equivalent to any sort of hierarchy.

If you train first using one distribution, and then the second distribution, then the network would probably just forget the class distribution from the first half of training -- in that case, why not make all batches drawn from the true distribution?

Comment: Regarding the class distributions, the problem arises when it is a different one in the training set than test. Oversampling against class imbalance alterates class distribution and then can produce overclassification of the oversamples classes if the net only learned to mimic distribution and not really the features that help predict each class. 
Switching distributions in the middle would start with a pre-trained network (i.e. from a different point in the parametric space than random initialization, and probably a better one), so how would it "forget" the first half of training?